# itertools: How to generate n-tuple list out of (n-1)-tuple list and a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-itertools

I would like to create a list of n-tuples based on a list of (n-1)-tuples and a list.

Below a minimized example for n=3 and list length of 5.

```
import itertools

# create a list with 5 elements
t1_list = [x for x in range(1,6)]
print(t1_list)    # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

# create 2-tuples out of t1_list
t2 = itertools.combinations(t1_list,2)
t2_list = [x for x in t2]
print(t2_list)    # [(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5), (3, 4), (3, 5), (4, 5)]

# remove some tuples based on some criterion
del t2_list[1]
del t2_list[4]
print(t2_list)    # [(1, 2), (1, 4), (1, 5), (2, 3), (2, 5), (3, 4), (3, 5), (4, 5)]

# now create a list of 3-tuples based on t2_list and t1_list
# i.e. without combinations containing (1,3) and (2,4) because they have been removed
# ???

# Result should be:
# [(1, 2, 5), (1, 4, 5), (2, 3, 5), (3, 4, 5)]
```

I guess would not be a good idea to create all possible n-tuples from `t1_list` and then delete the ones which contain the removed (n-1)-tuples, because at a later stage I would like to do this with up to 10-tuples out of a 100 element list.

Is there maybe a smart way to do this with `itertools`?

**Edit:**  Clarification how to get to the desired result:

`(1, 2, 4)` is excluded because `(2, 4)` is not present in `t2_list` and `(1, 2, 3)` is excluded because `(1,3)` is not present in `t2_list`.

The general rule would be: a n-tuple will be included only if all its (n-1)-tuples are existing in the `t(n-1)_list`. Or the other way round: an n-tuple will be excluded if one or more of its (n-1)-tuples are missing in the `t(n-1)_list`.

Comment: I don't understand the result, for example, why isn't `(1, 2) + 4` giving `(1, 2, 4)` part of the result? Is it because you previously have deleted `(2, 4)` from `t2` and `(2, 4)` is part of this so this should be excluded (even if it should normally be part of the n-tuple)? Can you elaborate on the way your result is built? Precisely, is it only based on a composition of `t2` and `t1`, or does it also require to know what have been removed from `t2`?

Comment: Even if we exclude 2-tuples like in the previous example, why isn't `(1, 2, 3)` part of the result, both `(1, 2)` and `(2, 3)` are still present in `t2`. I guess maybe it's because `(1, 3)` isn't, so you even want to remove this combinations?

Comment: @cglacet, sorry, if it wasn't completely clear. Yes, you are right with your guesses. I will edit the question.

Comment: I have yet another question then, is `t2` always a combination from `t1`? (and would any subsequent `ti` also be?)

Comment: @cglacet, yes, you start generating 2-tuples from `t1_list`, then depending on a calculation you exclude some of the 2-tuples in `t2_list`, then you generate 3-tuples based on `t2_list` and `t1_list` (the result above). And again based on a calculation you exclude some of the 3-tuples in `t3_list`, then you generate 4-tuples based on the remaining `t3_list` and the `t1_list`, exclude again, etc., etc .... (note, always tuples without repetition/replacement).

Comment: Ok, that seems clear to me now. I'll have a look at this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's how far I've gotten in the meantime. The example below shows a list of length 6 (different from the original question).
The result seems to be correct. However, I don't know whether this is nice and efficient code, especially when `t1_list` will have 100 elements and it goes up to 8- or 10-tuples. I need to test further. Suggestions for improvements are very welcome.

**Code:**

```
### create n-tuples list based on (n-1)-tuples list and a list
import itertools

# create a list with nmax elements
nmax = 6
t1_list = [x for x in range(1,nmax+1)]
print("T1_list:", t1_list)

# create 2-tuples out of t1_list
t2 = itertools.combinations(t1_list,2)
t2_list = [x for x in t2]
print("T2_list:", t2_list)

# remove some tuples based on a calculation result
del t2_list[1]
del t2_list[4]
print("T2_list after removal of some elements:", t2_list)

def create_ntuple_list(tn1_list, t1_list):   # create n-tuples out of (n-1)_list and t1_list
    tn_list = []
    for tn1 in tn1_list:    # i.e. t(n-1)_list
        n = len(tn1) + 1        # determine n
        tn1max = max(tn1)
        for t1 in t1_list:
            if t1 > tn1max:
                tn_tmp = tuple(list(tn1)+[t1])
                tn1_iter = itertools.combinations(tn_tmp,n-1)
                for tn1_tmp in tn1_iter:
                    if tn1_tmp not in tn1_list:
                        break
                else:
                    tn_list.append(tn_tmp)
    return tn_list


# create 3-tuples
t3_list = create_ntuple_list(t2_list, t1_list)
print("T3_list:", t3_list)

# remove some tuples based on a calculation result
del t3_list[2]
print("T3_list after removal of some elements", t3_list)

# create 4-tuples
t4_list = create_ntuple_list(t3_list, t1_list)
print("T4_list:", t4_list)

### end of code
```

**Result:**

```
T1_list: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

T2_list: [(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6), (3, 4), (3, 5), (3, 6), (4, 5), (4, 6), (5, 6)]

T2_list after removal of some elements: [(1, 2), (1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6), (2, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6), (3, 4), (3, 5), (3, 6), (4, 5), (4, 6), (5, 6)]

T3_list: [(1, 2, 4), (1, 2, 5), (1, 2, 6), (1, 4, 5), (1, 4, 6), (1, 5, 6), (2, 4, 5), (2, 4, 6), (2, 5, 6), (3, 4, 5), (3, 4, 6), (3, 5, 6), (4, 5, 6)]

T3_list after removal of some elements [(1, 2, 4), (1, 2, 5), (1, 4, 5), (1, 4, 6), (1, 5, 6), (2, 4, 5), (2, 4, 6), (2, 5, 6), (3, 4, 5), (3, 4, 6), (3, 5, 6), (4, 5, 6)]

T4_list: [(1, 2, 4, 5), (1, 4, 5, 6), (2, 4, 5, 6), (3, 4, 5, 6)]
```